# Apply time shift on Pandas DataFrame from another column

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to add some seconds to a DateTime index of a Pandas DataFrame.

In order to do this I need to subtract the values from the other column:

```
>>> frame["s_eventdatetime"] = frame["eventdatetime"].apply(lambda x: x - datetime.timedelta(seconds=frame["seconds"])) 
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Series
```

Does someone know how to do this for the according row values, which are different in each row. There is no constant value. I think this fails because some rows have NaN entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a DataFrame, a column of values which come from `datetimes`/`Timestamps`/`DatetimeIndex`/`datetime64`'s are internally stored in a NumPy array of dtype `datetime64[ns]`.

To add or subtract a column of integers representing seconds, convert the integers to a NumPy array of `timedelta64[s]` dtype. You can then perform NumPy [datetime64/timedelta64 arithmetic](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
N = 10
frame = pd.DataFrame({'eventdatetime':pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='T'), 
                  'seconds': np.random.randint(60, size=N)})
frame.loc[::2, 'seconds'] = np.nan

frame["s_eventdatetime"] = (
    frame["eventdatetime"] - np.array(frame['seconds'].fillna(0), dtype='timedelta64[s]'))
```

yields

```
        eventdatetime  seconds     s_eventdatetime
0 2000-01-01 00:00:00      NaN 2000-01-01 00:00:00
1 2000-01-01 00:01:00       12 2000-01-01 00:00:48
2 2000-01-01 00:02:00      NaN 2000-01-01 00:02:00
3 2000-01-01 00:03:00        9 2000-01-01 00:02:51
4 2000-01-01 00:04:00      NaN 2000-01-01 00:04:00
5 2000-01-01 00:05:00        8 2000-01-01 00:04:52
6 2000-01-01 00:06:00      NaN 2000-01-01 00:06:00
7 2000-01-01 00:07:00       26 2000-01-01 00:06:34
8 2000-01-01 00:08:00      NaN 2000-01-01 00:08:00
9 2000-01-01 00:09:00       59 2000-01-01 00:08:01
```

---

You can also add NumPy arrays of `timedelta64[s]`s to Pandas DatetimeIndex's:

```
x = pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='T')
x - np.array(frame['seconds'], dtype='timedelta64[s]')
```

yields

```
In [23]: x
Out[23]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01 00:00:00', '2000-01-01 00:01:00',
               '2000-01-01 00:02:00', '2000-01-01 00:03:00',
               '2000-01-01 00:04:00', '2000-01-01 00:05:00',
               '2000-01-01 00:06:00', '2000-01-01 00:07:00',
               '2000-01-01 00:08:00', '2000-01-01 00:09:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T', tz=None)

In [24]: x - np.array(frame['seconds'], dtype='timedelta64[s]')
Out[24]: 
DatetimeIndex(['1999-12-31 23:59:26', '2000-01-01 00:00:48',
               '2000-01-01 00:01:26', '2000-01-01 00:02:51',
               '2000-01-01 00:03:38', '2000-01-01 00:04:52',
               '2000-01-01 00:05:14', '2000-01-01 00:06:34',
               '2000-01-01 00:07:47', '2000-01-01 00:08:01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='T', tz=None)
```

Comment: This definitely leads in the right direction. Do you have an idea how I can drop NaN values in that conversion? np.array(frame['seconds'].dropna(), dtype='timedelta64[s]') does not seem to be the way

Comment: Do you want the NaNs treated as 0 seconds? If so, you could use `frame["s_eventdatetime"] = frame["eventdatetime"] - np.array(frame['seconds'].fillna(0), dtype='timedelta64[s]')`.